# formatting matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, formatting

I'm writing a program that uses a mean filter to smooth an image. right now I'm not using an actual image, just integers and my issue is that I can get the average of the left hand corner number, the average of the numbers on the left side, and the average of the numbers in the middle but when it outputs the results, it's not outputting back into a matrix.

Ex. user is asked for a number for Rows and Columns: input is 5 and 5
a 5x5 matrix is out put

but then i'm getting these results for the averages in a top to bottom fashion

```
  50
  50
  71
  65
  61
  48  64  57
  59  26  61
  43  63  20
```

The output I'm trying to achieve is

```
  50
  71  48  64  57
  65  59  26  61
  61  43  63  20
```

Obviously this isn't a finished product seeing as how I have yet to program the averages for the rest of the matrix, but this formatting issue is driving me nuts.

heres the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>  
#include <time.h>
// function that randomly generates numbers 
void fillArray(int a[10][20], int m, int n)
{

  int random;
  int i,j;  
  for (i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
      for (j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
          random=rand()%100;
          a[i][j]=random;
      }
  }
}

// function that prints the first matrix of random numbers
void printarray (int a[10][20], int m, int n)
{
 int i,j;
 for (i=0;i<m;i++) 
 {
     for (j=0;j<n;j++)
     {
         printf("%4d", a[i][j]);
     }
     printf("\n");
 }
}

// function that finds the mean for any number and its 4 nieghbors 
void corner1 (int a[10][20], int n, int m)
{
 int c[10][20];
 int i,j;
 for (i=0;i<m;i++) 
 {
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        if (i<=0 && j<=0)
        {
           c[i][j]=(a[i+1][j]+a[i][j+1])/2;
           printf("%4d",c[i][j]);
        }
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
}



void middle(int a[10][20], int n, int m)
{
 int c[10][20];
 int i,j;
 for (i=1;i<m-1;i++) 
 {
    for (j=1;j<n-1;j++)
    {
        c[i][j]=(a[i-1][j]+a[i][j-1]+a[i+1][j]+a[i][j+1])/4;
        printf("%4d",c[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
 }
}

void side1 (int a[10][20], int n, int m)
{
 int c[10][20];
 int i,j;
 for (i=1;i<m;i++) 
 {
    for (j=0;j<n-1;j++)
    {
      if (i<=1&&j>=0)
      {
         c[i][j]=(0+0+a[i-1][j]+a[i+1][j]+a[i][j+1])/3; 
         printf("%4d",c[i][j]);
         printf("\n");
      }  
    }     
  }
}

int main()
{
 int a[10][20];

 int m,n;
 srand(time(NULL));

 //User input
 printf("please enter number of rows and columns\n");
 scanf("%d %d", &m,&n);
 fillArray(a,m,n);
 printarray (a,m,n);
 printf("The smoothed image is\n");
 side1(a,m,n);
 corner1(a,m,n);
 middle (a,m,n);
 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your `printarray` method working as expected? Seems that the `printf("\n")` statements are not well placed in the other functions...

Comment: Is that really copy/pasted output? I see %4d in your code, but only 3 characters per column in your output.

Comment: Also, I'm unclear what the question is. Do you want us to rewrite your code to make it work, or are you asking why you're getting the output you're getting?

Comment: Yannick, the printarray works as expected. @Crazycasta, I did not directly copy/paste the output, but that is the format that it's outputting at. The %4d is used for spacing when printing out the columns. I did not necessarily intend to have everyone rewrite the code, but if someone would like to, then I could compare it to the mistakes I made and use it as reference for the future. Thanks

Comment: That is not the exact format, and some picky people will wonder what the actual format is (myself included, I went and compiled it to make sure). We would really prefer that people copy/paste where possible. I'll edit it with the numbers I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions I can see off the top of my head:

1. Have corner1, side1 and middle store in an array. Print the array out when you're done (instead of inside corner1, side1, and middle).
2. Iterate through each of the rows. Call side1 on the row, don't print the newline, call middle on the row. This would be somewhat less efficient because of the numerous calls (for a larger image), and doesn't reuse your printarray code so I would suggest you use option 1.

Comment: My apologies for the poor formatting, I will keep that in mind for next time. I'm going to give number 1 a try and see if that fixes my issue. I tried storing them all in one function earlier, and that didn't go so well. Thanks for the help, hopefully you wont be hearing back from me haha.

Comment: is there anyway to store those functions into an array while the functions are void?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. If you're asking for an array of functions so you can just do a for loop instead of 4-5 function calls then what you want are [function pointers](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/function_pointers.html). The voidness of the return value has no bearing on the ability to use function pointers.

Comment: Basically I'm just trying to set corner1,side1, and middle to an array like you suggest. Forgive me for my lack of knowledge, I'm working on this for a class, and we just started going over arrays, but the professor was very vague and short when he talked about it in class. I've basically had to teach myself over the last week while I've worked on this project and I'm getting frustrated because I feel like this is a lot easier then I'm making it. I need to have this completed by tomorrow night. So far you've been my biggest resource.

Comment: I think what you're asking is whether you can store the return value of the function in an array (note we can store functions in an array by taking their pointer, but this is not what you want). The strict answer is no, you can not store the return value in an array (or for that matter anything into the array as a whole). However, what you can do (and probably want to do) is pass the output array into the function. Arrays pass by reference in C, so any changes you make to the array inside the function will be reflected in the values in the array in the function that called it.